# PHP Date not calculating properly

Tags: php

I have this code, and it prints out as '01/01/1970'

```
$dob = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1, date("y")-18);
echo "DOB is ".date("d/m/y", $dob);
```

Why is the year not 18 years less than today?

Comment: Try it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ (It gives 15/09/03.  As if you used "Y".  Weird.  Ideone and codepad give 01/01/70.)

Comment: @Ray Toal: or http://codepad.org/

Comment: @Sayem Edited the comment.  I was pointing out writecodeonline for some reason is treating y as Y.  I don't know why!

Comment: @Ray Toal: Yup, you are right.That's weird.........

Answer (score 5):

`date("y") == 11` and `11-18 == -7`. You need `date("Y") == 2011`.

Debugging tip: Print out separate parts of the code so you see what's going on. `echo $dob` shows that the problem is on the first line, and `echo date("y")-18` tells that it's the last argument to `mktime()` that causes it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest solution :

```
$dob = strtotime('-18 years');
echo date('d/m/y', $dob);
```

`strtotime()` is a powerful function.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$dob = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-1, date("Y")-18);
echo "DOB is ".date("d/m/y", $dob);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), when you specify small `y` as the argument to `date` function, it will return two-digit representation of the current year. Since the current year is 2011, it will return 11. Subtracting 18 from it will give you a negative result, that's why `mktime` is resetting to the original timestamp.

Change `date("y")` to `date("Y")`, that is, replace small `y` with capital `Y`, then you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is imho much easier to read:

```
<?php
$dob = new DateTime();
printf("\nToday is %s", date_format($dob, 'D, M d Y'));
$dob->modify('-1 day');
$dob->modify('-18 year');
printf("\nToday minus %d day and %d year is %s", 
         -1, -18, 
         date_format($dob, 'D, M d Y'));
?>
```

Don't you agree? It is not so difficult to calculate date with PHP. Just look also at the PHP Date function for the various formats, such as Weeknumbers.